Search within a onedrive folder using graph api search endpoint ( /v1.0/search/query)
I managed to search within a onedrive folder using the search api (/v1.0/search/query)
with body:

{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": ["driveItem"],
            "fields": ["id", "name", "file", "folder", "parentReference", "lastModifiedDateTime", "size", "webUrl", "mimeType", "fileType", "metadata", "title", "parentLink", "path", "name"],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "title:image* AND (parentLink:https://my.sharepoint.com/personal/tony/Documents/test*)"
            },
            "from": 0,
            "size": 100
        }
    ]
}

The issue is that I have another folder name "test (1)", with the body above, it returns all data from two folders test and test (1), I only want to search all files/folder (nested files/folders too) within "test" folder.
I tried to remove * out of parentLink but results still include files from test (1) folder.
The reason I put * after parentLink is that I want to also search for files in nested folders inside test folder.
What I did to workaround is that I add an extra filter function in my code after receiving data from the request to onedrive, it worked but then I don't know how to handle pagination the endpoint support.
Any idea how to make it work in this case ? I browsered document from this Graph API Search API but couldn't find any clue to fix the issue.

I would use path instead of parentLink to specify in which folder and all its subfolders should be search performed.
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": ["driveItem"],
            "fields": ["id", "name", "file", "folder", "parentReference", "lastModifiedDateTime", "size", "webUrl", "mimeType", "fileType", "metadata", "title", "parentLink", "path", "name"],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "title:image* AND path:\"https://my.sharepoint.com/personal/tony/Documents/test\""
            },
            "from": 0,
            "size": 100
        }
    ]
}


Thanks, but in my case some files have the paths different which don't contain folder path, somethings like https://my.sharepoint.com/personal/tony/Documents/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=788.
With * at the end, some files from test (1) also return in the result.
Without * at the end, it tried to search for files which exact folder path, which can exclude files with different paths as I show above.
